# PHP array to JavaScript array using json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

How do I pass an array from PHP to the JavaScript function `console.log()`? I'm simulating a DB. I understand that I don't have an array declared in the code. I've tried using the .getJSON() function but it didn't work. Should I do an AJAX call for each element? I was thinking about that but there has to be a better way.

#### JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
         method:"POST",
         url:'php.php',
         data:"",
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(data){
             var y1=data;
             console.log(data.name);
         }
      });
```

#### PHP code:

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    //assign vars after formatting to avoid a wrong login with correct 
    //username and password
    $username = trim($_POST["user"]);


   $customer_array = array();

    $customer1 = array(
        'name' => '3',
        'city' => 'Houston'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer1;

    $customer2 = array(
        'name' => '2',
        'city' => 'Boston'
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer2;

    $customer3 = array(
        'name' => "1",
        'city' => "Bossier City"
    );

    echo json_encode($customer_array);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get data.name because you stored your associate arrays inside a standard array. Should be some thing like `data[0].name` because it would be in an object like `[{"name":"something","city":something"},{"name":"some name","city":something else"}]`, try just `console.log(data);` see if that comes through as the object

Comment: Also it's not `method:"POST"` it's `type:"POST"`, right now you are probably sending a `$_GET`

Comment: It might also be useful to send an action in the `data` and check for it in the file instead of just checking for a post, especially if you expand upon this script in the future: `data:{"action":"get_name_city"}`, then in the PHP it would look like `if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'get_name_city') { etc...`.

Comment: @Rasclatt The `method:` option was added in jQuery 1.9. It's equivalent to `type:`.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't know that, learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to summarize my comments into an answer, first I would just turn off the `json` return for trouble shooting. You can parse the json after fact anyway:

```
$.ajax({
    // Do "type" here
    type:"POST",
    url:'php.php',
    // Send something to check in the script
    // This is optional, but I like to do it...
    data: {
        "action":"get_name_city"
    },
    success:function(data){
        // Do a try, just incase your parse fails
        try {
            // Parse the json here
            var getJson = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(getJson);
            console.log(data);
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            // Show any errors that might get thrown
            console.log(Exception.message);
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
# Check the action is set and is named
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "get_name_city") {
    $username = trim($_POST["user"]);
    $customer_array = array();

    $customer1 = array(
        'name' => '3',
        'city' => 'Houston'
    );

    $customer2 = array(
        'name' => '2',
        'city' => 'Boston'
    );

    $customer3 = array(
        'name' => "1",
        'city' => "Bossier City"
    );

    $customer_array[] = $customer1;
    $customer_array[] = $customer2;
    $customer_array[] = $customer3;

    # Just die here
    die(json_encode($customer_array));
}
# Die with error so there is some feedback to your ajax
die(json_encode(array('error'=>'No data was sent.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there. Your AJAX requests accepts JSON but your PHP does not output JSON (it does but not in the correct way), you'll have to set the appropriate `Content-Type` header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($customer_array);
```

Your AJAX request should now be able to use the properly formatted JSON as the `data` variable (and `console.log` it).

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, there are multiple options for passing the data from PHP:

- add the **Content-Type** header with value *application/json* before sending the return from [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to [echo()](http://php.net/echo):

  ```
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($customer_array);
  ```
- Parse the return from the PHP using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

  ```
  success:function(data){
      var y1=data;
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
  ```

So pick one of those approaches. One might argue that the first is more semantically correct, since JSON data is being sent.

Additionally, the success callback of the AJAX request is attempting to access the property *name* of the data returned. However, the data returned should be an array of objects, each which has a property *name*. One approach to logging the name of each property is to use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) and send the name of each element in the array to [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

```
data.forEach(function(dataItem) {
    console.log(dataItem.name);
});
```

See a demonstration of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3f4t-mgqa).